# Submit Formassembly form via api

Tags: php, wordpress, form-submit

I got a form (caldera) on wordpress that collects data and after submission I need to transfer some of its fields to Salesforce via formassembly form.

I got all the credentials needed to connect to formassembly via api (aka, $CLIENT_ID and $CLIENT_SECRET). I read the documentation on [github](https://github.com/veerwest/formassembly-api/tree/master/php) regarding how to connect to formassembly.

I can connect to formassembly via postman but unable to submit my test data (I'm using curl). 
what API_REQUEST I need to use in order to submit the form?

When I use 
https://app.formassembly.com/api_v1/forms/index.json?access_token=xxxxxx

I get a response —> json with several forms.

When I use
https://app.formassembly.com/rest/forms/view/#formid#

I get an html of my form, but the data is not submitted.

I would really appreciate any help with that!
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the Formassembly API is designed for submitting form data. However, you should be able to use curl (or any other approach) to POST data directly to Formassembly.
Make sure your a POSTing, and that your header contains Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, and that you are sending to https://www.tfaforms.com/responses/processor.
You will also need to inspect the embeddable markup Formassembly provides to find the correct form data to submit. Make sure you have both the correct tfa_dbFormId and tfa_dbControl information.